# Change the color of the datatables dropdown list for choosing entries value

Tags: c#, datatable

[This blue color is that i want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZWr9.png)

I tried to look inside datatables options but I can't find where to change it.

This is the original site form where i download code:
https://datatables.net/

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF? If it is WPF I am sure you can dabble with the styles but if it is WinForms you are in a treat since this means inheriting ComboBox and overriding OnPaint method.

Comment: C# project, i show data on index view in table format

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase this. What technology do you use for UI. Is it WPF, is it WinForms, is it HTML? C# means nothing to me when you are asking an UI question.

Comment: HTML, i am sorry

Comment: If you are using native combo box than it is not possible(at least not for all browsers). You would have to resort to a custom solution where you would use <ul> in your drop down. That you can style! Have you considered using a 3rd party combo box?